# python args not working unless it has a position reference

Tags: python, args

```
def test_stats(team, *args):

    if not args:
          [do some stuff]
    else:

        team_fixtures = (Fixtures.objects.filter(home_team=team_details.id) | Fixtures.objects.filter(away_team=team_details.id))/
.filter(fixture_datetime__lt=datetime.now()).filter(fixture_datetime__year=args[0])
```

And for reference sake - args is:

```
date_year = datetime.now().year
```

for this query to work i need to reference args as

```
.filter(fixture_datetime__year=args[0])
```

because if I use

```
.filter(fixture_datetime__year=args)
```

I get the error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'tuple'

I understand that it thinks it's a tuple even though it's only one value but when I do the following in terminal

```
type(date_year)
```

I get class  back.

Why do I have to reference position here when it looks to be just one value returning?

Comment: `*args` is *always* a tuple.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You seem to answer everything in your question already. If you provide exactly one argument  `bar` to `foo(*args)` then `args == (bar,)`. But reading your post you already knew that.

Comment: @timegb OP is asking why if he passes `date_year` in the function call, why it is passed as a tuple of length 1, instead of the integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*`-prefixed argument is **always** a tuple. It captures 0 or more extra positional arguments. You can call your `test_stats()` function with 3 or 20 or 100 extra arguments (beyond the explicit `team` argument), and they all would be part of the `args` tuple in the function:

```
>>> def foo(*args): return args
...
>>> foo()
()
>>> foo(42)
(42,)
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

If you wanted *one* optional argument, make it a keyword argument with a sentinel default, like `None`:

```
def test_stats(team, optional=None):
    if optional is None:
        # ...
    else:
        team_fixtures = (
            Fixtures.objects.filter(home_team=team_details.id) |
            Fixtures.objects.filter(away_team=team_details.id))
                .filter(fixture_datetime__lt=datetime.now())
                .filter(fixture_datetime__year=optional)
        )
```

Comment: Might be worth still addressing that `foo(1)` would return `(1,)`. In case anyone thinks a single argument is an exception.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: done, using my favourite integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are receiving date as a second argument then explicitly define it in signature

```
def test_stats(team, date):
```

If you can pass there also something different then use keyword arguments

```
def test_stats(team, date=None, something_else=None):
```

`*args` should be used only if you want to pass sequence of arguments without creating a sequence beforehand

```
def get_integers(*args):
    return args


>>> get_integers(1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11)
(1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11)
```

`*args` is a tuple and `**kwargs` is a dictionary.